# Get Removed/Duplicates Key values from Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First of all this is not a duplicate as i haven't found any info about this.
We can successfully remove duplicate values using the following from an array **for example:**

```
 $messages=   Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [user] => 2224 [sending_time] => 1536513903 [read_time] => 1536513941 [content] => sad [recipient_status] => read ) 
        [1] => Array ( [user] => 3310 [sending_time] => 1536513903 [read_time] => 1536513941 [content] => sad [recipient_status] => read ) 
        [2] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513874 [read_time] => 1536567672 [content] => def [recipient_status] => read ) 
        [3] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513532 [read_time] => 1536513745 [content] => abc [recipient_status] => read ) 
    )
```

Using the following i can remove the duplicates(by key):

```
        $MSGS_array  = array();
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $MSGS_array[$message['user']] = $message;
        }
```

But the question is how can i get the removed **user** key value?

OR

How can i get all the duplicates having key **user** and their **value(s)** in an array from the array above?

**Expected Output:**

The output should only contain the removed/duplicates Like:(i just need the duplicates with they key **user**)

```
 $output=   Array (
        [0] => Array ( [user] => user1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [user] => user1 ) 
 );
```

**OR**

```
 $output=   Array (
        [0] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513874 [read_time] => 1536567672 [content] => def [recipient_status] => read ) 
        [1] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513532 [read_time] => 1536513745 [content] => abc [recipient_status] => read ) 
 );
```

Comment: None of the entries in your example are exact duplicates of one of the others... what makes an entry a duplicate?

Comment: please check [3] and [4] array having value 'user1' similar.

Comment: Please check the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to find the duplicate messages. First we find the non-unique users by checking the count of the values of `user`. Then we filter the messages in `$messages` by seeing if the `user` is in the non-unique users array:

```
$non_unique_users = array_filter(array_count_values(array_column($messages, 'user')), function ($v) { return $v != 1; });
$duplicate_messages = array_filter($messages, function ($v) use($non_unique_users) { return array_key_exists($v['user'], $non_unique_users); });
print_r($duplicate_messages);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [2] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513874 [read_time] => 1536567672 [content] => def [recipient_status] => read ) 
    [3] => Array ( [user] => user1 [sending_time] => 1536513532 [read_time] => 1536513745 [content] => abc [recipient_status] => read ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/i43YG)

**Update**

To just return an array of the `user` keys, you can apply `array_map` to the `$duplicate_messages` array:

```
$duplicate_users = array_map(function ($v) { return array('user' => $v['user']); }, $duplicate_messages);
```

or you can derive it directly from the `$messages` and `$non_unique_users` arrays:

```
$duplicate_users = array_map(function ($v) use($non_unique_users) { if (array_key_exists($v['user'], $non_unique_users)) return array('user' => $v['user']); }, $duplicate_messages);
```

In both cases the output is

```
Array ( 
    [2] => Array ( [user] => user1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [user] => user1 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1LNc5)

Comment: Thanks this is working but how can i get the **user key and value only **without the rest sending_time,read_time etc.

Comment: @MR_AMDEV see my edit. That should give you what you want.